# image is not being set in custom list

Tags: android, android-imageview

Im picking an `image` from `gallery` and saving its path in `sqlite DB`, all things are working good, but the `image` is not set in `ImageView`.
`MyAdapter.java` class is :

```
public class MyAdapter extends CursorAdapter {

protected Activity activity = null;


public MyAdapter(Activity activity, Cursor cursor) {
    super(activity, cursor, false);     
    this.activity = activity;
}

@Override
public void bindView(View row, Context context, Cursor cursor) {

    MyHolder holder = (MyrHolder) row.getTag();
    holder.populateFrom(cursor);
}

@Override
public View newView(Context context, Cursor cursor, ViewGroup root) {

    LayoutInflater inflater = activity.getLayoutInflater();

    View row = inflater.inflate(R.layout.row, root, false);
    MyHolder holder = new MyHolder(activity, row);
    row.setTag(holder);

    return (row);
}
```

}

`MyHolder.java` class is :

```
public class MyHolder {

protected Activity activity = null;
protected TextView name, phone, dateOfJoining;
protected ImageView imageView = null;

    public MyHolder(Activity activity, View row) {

    this.activity = activity;
    name = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.name);
    phone = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.phone);
    dateOfJoining = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.joinDate);
    imageView = (ImageView) row.findViewById(R.id.imageView);
}

    public void populateFrom(Cursor cursor) {

        name.setText(cursor.getString(0));
        phone.setText("Cell : " + cursor.getString(1));
        dateOfJoining.setText(cursor.getString(2));         
        imageView.setImageBitmap(getImageBitmap(cursor));


}

protected Bitmap getImageBitmap(Cursor cursor) {

    Bitmap bitmap = null;
    try {
        bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(cursor.getString(3));
    } catch (Exception e) {

        bitmap =BitmapFactory.decodeResource(activity.getResources(), R.drawable.person);
    }
    Log.e("IAMGE", "Path is = " + cursor.getString(3));
    return bitmap;
}}
```

but image is not set in `imageView` at line `imageView.setImageBitmap(getImageBitmap(cursor));`.
please tell how to set this problem..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There may be some more options, but I think you should give correct column index at line

```
bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(cursor.getString(3));
```

this may be helpful for you...

Comment: Alas! there you are, changing `bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(cursor.getString(3));` to `bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(cursor.getString(4));` Im getting correct results thank for tricky help...

Answer (score 0):

In the code provided you are creating instance of MemberHolder in newView and you have pasted code for MyHolder, So I am assuming that MemberHolder and MyHolder are same and it is some typo...

You are creating instance of Member Holder which should be ideally of MyHolder.....

```
MemberHolder holder = new MemberHolder(activity, row);
```

populateFrom method of holder is the method which populates the view, but it doesn't seems to be called from any where probably that is the reason that View is not getting populated and ImageView is also empty.

Comment: ok I have fixed that and got the path `= /mnt/sdcard/DCIM/ic_launcher.png`, but still `Image` is not set.

Answer (score 0):

try this...

remove

```
holder.populateFrom(cursor);
```

from

```
bindView(View row, Context context, Cursor cursor)
```

method and keep it in newView(...) method like

```
@Override
public View newView(Context context, Cursor cursor, ViewGroup root) {
     LayoutInflater inflater = activity.getLayoutInflater();
     View row = inflater.inflate(R.layout.row, root, false);
     MyHolder holder = new MyHolder(activity, row);
     row.setTag(holder);
     holder.populateFrom(cursor);
     return (row);
}
```

Comment: I have tried this, instead of solving this problem it creates an other one as well, which is if I add new record the first one is repeated and new one is not being populated...